# Fn key is not functioning on SAMSUNG NP-RV513 laptop

Tags: shortcut-keys, laptop, samsung

I cannot adjust brightness, Sound etc.. using <kbd>Fn</kbd> key in my Samsung NP-RV513 laptop. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32bit  as a dual boot with windows 7.

```
Processor: AMD Dual Core Processor E-350 (1.6GHz, 1MB) 
Chipset: AMD A50M FCH.
```

Please help me to find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

A PPA repository exists that deal with being able to use the controls and FN keys of your samsung device.

You can add it by using the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:voria/ppa
```

Now you need to upgrade your apt cache by using:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now you can install the 2 packages that give back access to FN keys:

```
sudo apt-get install samsung-tools
sudo apt-get install samsung-laptop
```

You can find more information about the Voria packages here:

http://www.voria.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1091

### Note

This only works if your laptop is supported by the kernel. Since these packages use the existing brigthness controls. It only gives you the missing connection between the FN keys and the existing brightness controls. So your laptop must be supported by the kernel.

Comment: You solved my question from 3 months back that noone could..!! Thanx thanx thanx thanx..!!! i can only put one upvote..!! i would have put hundreeds if possible..!! thanx a ton.!!! this was my question 3 months back-http://askubuntu.com/q/105534/46000

Comment: This will not solve my problem.hope ubuntu will resolve this in upcoming releases,Thanks